# If 'Other ' option is selected in dropbox the textfield should appear and the value of textfield should be sent to DB

Tags: php

I have a Drop box with one value as 'Other', when I select that option I'm able to get text field, but after submitting the Form, the value of Dropbox in DB is 'Other' where it should be the text inserted by the user in Text field

Below is the HTML CODE :-

```
<select name="Branch[]" class="form-control name_list" id="Other">
    <option>Select option</option>
    <option value="Information Technology">Information Technology</option>
    <option value="Computer Engineering">Computer Engineering</option>
    <option value="Civil EngineeringE">Civil Engineering</option>
    <option value="Electronics">Electronics</option>
    <option value="Mechanical">Mechanical</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
<div id="otherType" style="display:none;">
    <label for="specify">Specify</label>
    <input type="text" name="Branch[]" placeholder="Specify Databse Type" />
</div>
```

Below is the Javascript Code :-

```
$('#Other').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() === "other") {
        $("#otherType").show()
    } else {
        $("#otherType").hide()
    }
});
```

Following the php code which is working fine for other options but not for option 'others'

```
if($number3 > 0)
                                    {
                                        for($k=0; $k<$number3; $k++)
                                        {
                                            if(trim($_POST["qualification"][$k] != ''))
                                            {
                                            $sql3 = "INSERT INTO edudetails VALUES('$biocode','".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["qualification"][$k])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["course"][$k])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["Branch"][$k])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["University"][$k])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["PassYear"][$k])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["Class"][$k])."')";

                                            mysqli_query($db, $sql3);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
```

Comment: Post the php code

Comment: You have to update the value of `Branch` before saving.

Comment: but where's your php code? and don't make it an array, as it's a select (not a multiple select). So `name="Branch"` is good

Comment: @SougataBose Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: @Giorgio array is required as i have added a button which is not shown here . the button simply creates Multiple selects

Comment: you should prepare each array separately. There's no guarantee they all have the same amount of options selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change `Branch[]` input name to another one (you can simple use `OtherBranch[]` instead)
2. Before insert data to db, just check if `$_POST["Branch"][$k] === 'other'` then you should take `$_POST["OtherBranch"][$k]` as branch value.

Updated:

It's better to update your code:

```
if($number3 > 0)  {
    for($k=0; $k<$number3; $k++)  {
        $qualification = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["qualification"][$k]);
        $course = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["course"][$k]);
        $branch = $_POST["Branch"][$k] !== 'other' 
            ? mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["Branch"][$k]) 
            : mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["OtherBranch"][$k]);
        $university = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["University"][$k]);
        $passYear = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["PassYear"][$k]);
        $class = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["Class"][$k]);
        if(trim($_POST["qualification"][$k] != '')) {
            $sql3 = "INSERT INTO edudetails
                     VALUES('$biocode', '$qualification', '$course', '$branch', '$university', '$passYear', '$class')";
            mysqli_query($db, $sql3);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this help!